# Summing a column via relationship with core data

Tags: xcode, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to modify Mike Swans [Core Data Expenses tutorial](http://www.themikeswan.com/blog/?p=81) to have a table with a list of categories in one column and their balances in the next column.

I've tried binding the value of the second column to:

```
1. CategoryController.arrangedObjects.transactions.@sum.amount
2. CategoryController.arrangedObjects.@sum.transactions.@sum.amount
```

Number 2 seemed to work briefly with existing entries but it's obviously not correct as I can't get it to work again. The message I'm getting is

```
[<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x100166b00> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: @sum.amount
```

Should this be possible without code? It seems strange that I can easily get the @sum for the selected category into a label but not for the whole list into a column...

I found [this message on the developer list](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/284583-core-data-binding-to-sum.html) and thought it might be the answer I was after but if so I was hoping someone might be able to explain it a bit better. I tried creating a new array controller but everything I've tried seemed to be leading me deeper and deeper into a programming abyss.

EDIT:-
I fixed a separate issue with binding to the wrong controller and thought I'd revisit this. Both of the above options sort of work (the columns tally) but when I try to add a new category they both cause that  exception. Trying to remove an existing category causes another exception (which I presume is the inverse of the first):

```
Cannot remove an observer <NSTableBinder 0x10017e5b0> for the key path "transactions.@sum.amount" from <NSManagedObject 0x10303dda0> because it is not registered as an observer
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you, but I just encountered a similar problem whereby binding an NSTextField to the sum of one of my fields (arrayController.arrangedObjects.@sum.duration) would throw an exception, whereas binding to arrayController.selection.@sum.duration worked fine.

I ended up putting it in code, like:

```
// In my ViewController class.
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [totalLabel bind:@"value" toObject:arrayController
         withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.@sum.duration" 
             options:nil];
}
```

...and it appears to work as expected.